# Understanding vtkSmartPointers

Tags: c++, vtk

In a project using VTK, I'm trying to use the [VTK Pointer Classes](https://blog.kitware.com/a-tour-of-vtk-pointer-classes/) in the correct way to avoid memory leaks.

It is my understanding that objects created with `vtkSmartPointer<...>::New()` will be deleted automatically when they get out of scope. Therefore I don't fully understand why my code example here below runs correctly. I would have expected the filters defined in `applyFilters(...)` to be deleted on return, and therefore my program to segfault. Instead, it runs correctly and returns `vtkDebugLeaks has found no leaks.` (hooray!).

Why exactly does this work? I have the vague idea that it's the refcounting keeping the objects alive on the heap. Does this mean that I don't have to keep every VTK object I create in a member variable if I were to implement this pipeline in a separate class, and that I could only keep the most important objects, call ->Delete() when I'm finished, and let the VTK refcounting do the memory clean-up of the rest?  Somehow this doesn't feel right..

**pointertest.cxx**

```
#include <vtkPolyData.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataMapper.h>
#include <vtkActor.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkStructuredGrid.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkCellCenters.h>
#include <vtkDoubleArray.h>
#include <vtkCellDataToPointData.h>
#include <vtkCellData.h>
#include <vtkClipDataSet.h>
#include <vtkPlane.h>
#include <vtkCutter.h>
#include <vtkPolyDataAlgorithm.h>


vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataAlgorithm>
applyFilters(vtkSmartPointer<vtkStructuredGrid> grid)
{
  // Convert cell data to point data
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellDataToPointData> c2p =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellDataToPointData>::New();
  c2p->PassCellDataOn();
  c2p->SetInputData(grid);

  // Clip at value r = 4.5
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet> clip =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkClipDataSet>::New();
  clip->SetInputConnection(c2p->GetOutputPort());
  clip->SetInputArrayToProcess(0, 0, 0, 0, "R");
  clip->SetValue(4.5);
  clip->InsideOutOn();

  // Make plane
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane> plane =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlane>::New();
  plane->SetOrigin(0.,0.,0.);
  plane->SetNormal(0, 0, 1);

  // Cut
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCutter> cutter =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCutter>::New();
  cutter->SetCutFunction(plane);
  cutter->SetInputConnection(clip->GetOutputPort());

  return cutter;
}


int main()
{
  // Create structured grid
  int nx = 101, ny = 101, nz = 101;
  double dx, dy, dz;
  dx = dy = dz = 10./(nx-1);
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkStructuredGrid> grid =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkStructuredGrid>::New();
  grid->SetDimensions(nx, ny, nz);
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> pts = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
  for (int i = 0; i < nx; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ny; ++j) {
      for (int k = 0; k < nz; ++k) {
        pts->InsertNextPoint(-5+dx*i, -5+dy*j, -5+dz*k);
      }
    }
  }
  grid->SetPoints(pts);

  // Create cell scalar field
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray> arr =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkDoubleArray>::New();
  arr->SetNumberOfComponents(1);
  arr->SetName("R");
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellCenters> cell_centres =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellCenters>::New();
  cell_centres->SetInputData(grid);
  cell_centres->Update();
  for (int i = 0; i < grid->GetNumberOfCells(); ++i) {
    double pt[3];
    cell_centres->GetOutput()->GetPoint(i, pt);
    double r = pt[0]*pt[0] + pt[1]*pt[1] + pt[2]*pt[2];
    arr->InsertNextValue(r);
  }
  grid->GetCellData()->AddArray(arr);

  // Call clipping functions
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataAlgorithm> poly_algo = applyFilters(grid);

  // Create a mapper and actor
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
  mapper->SetInputConnection(poly_algo->GetOutputPort());
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
  actor->SetMapper(mapper);

  // Create a renderer, render window and interactor
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> render_window =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
  render_window->SetWindowName("Plane");
  render_window->AddRenderer(renderer);
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> window_interactor =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
  window_interactor->SetRenderWindow(render_window);

  // Add the actors to the scene
  renderer->AddActor(actor);

  // Render and interact
  render_window->Render();
  window_interactor->Start();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If needed, it can be compiled using cmake with the following file:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(PointerTest)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(pointerTest pointertest.cxx )

target_link_libraries(pointerTest ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: The key point is the smart pointers are reference counting. `poly_algo` will make sure they are not destroyed until main() ends.

Comment: You should never (or only in very specific scenarios) need to explicitly `Delete()` reference counted objects. That's pretty much the point, everything will be handled automatically for you

Comment: @drescherjm So I don't need to keep a copy of all the vtkObjects I created during the lifetime of my pipepline?

Comment: @UnholySheep Undersood. The idea was to perhaps do a DeepCopy of some reduced PolyData, and clear the memory of the bigger objects, like the structured grid.

Comment: as a side note, if you want on object to be destroyed when they get out of scope, use vtkNew.